# Dispatch.main.async invalid number of rows in section

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, dispatch

I'm having an issue when I check off my task to quickly, which makes the app crash and gives me error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

**Code when radiobutton tapped**

```
func RadioTapped(_ cell: TableViewCell) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        // Removes task from coreData
        let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]

        self.context.delete(task)
        do {
            self.tasks = try self.context.fetch(TodayTask.fetchRequest())
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            // Animate the removal of task cell
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(800),execute: {
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)                    
            })
        } catch {
            print("Fetching failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (9), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

This crash means when you are deleting your table row. You are not updating your arrayCount for instance you have defined 8 inside your `numberOfRowsInSection` method then before you delete the row you will also need to update the rows count based on the rows you want to delete. Otherwise when your `deleteRows` will called it will also called the `numberOfRowsInSection` method and there count will mismatch and it will crash.

Comment: ok but how can I update the numberOfRowsInSection then? Reload the tableview?

Comment: So before deleting the rows update your count value in variable and return that variable inside numberOfRows method.

Comment: Also Invoking reloadData is not required. Otherwise there will be no use of deleteRows method.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would I do that?

Comment: What you are returning inside numberOfRows method??

Comment: I'm returing tasks.count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150474/discussion-between-j-doe-and-hussain-shabbir).

Comment: Yes so update your tasks array before deleting the row.